# Are there HTTP headers that could reasonably be present multiple times?

Tags: http, cookies, http-headers

When I look at the list of standard HTTP headers for requests and responses on Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_header), most headers are only reasonable when they occur once in a request or a response.

Most. Not all. Especially the `Cookie` in a request and `Set-Cookie` in a response could be present multiple times when we are dealing with multiple cookies to be set by the server or transmitted back by the client.

When the server wants to set multiple cookies, there is one `Set-Cookie` header for each one. The client then presents these cookies with one `Cookie` header for each.

Apart of cookies: are there other HTTP headers that could be present multiple times (in a valid HTTP request)?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could  you need to know this. Are you writing an HTTP parser and do you have an actual problem? Do you have an existing library that explodes upon encountering a certain HTTP request or response? Do you "just want to know"? Did you try reading the relevant RFC's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2

> Multiple message-header fields with the same field-name MAY be
> present in a message if and **only if the entire field-value for that
> header field is defined as a comma-separated list** [i.e., #(values)].